# What historical similarities are there to Burr's characterization in "Hamilton"?

Tags: historical-context, hamilton-musical, lin-manuel-miranda

In the 2015 musical, *Hamilton* written by Lin-Manuel Miranda, Aaron Burr serves as the foil to Alexander Hamilton. While Alexander is rash, hasty, and always on the move, Aaron sits back and watches for things to happen, as a passive bystander. Essentially, Hamilton's philosophy seems to be to "make an opportunity" while Burr's seems to be "wait for an opportunity". This is best seen in the song, "Wait for it," where he sings,

> And if there's a reason I'm still alive
>   When everyone who loves me has died
>   I'm willing to wait for it.
>   I'm willing to wait for it.

Is this characterization consistent/based on who Burr historically was? Or was this simply a creative liberty Lin-Manuel Miranda took to highlight the foil that would also serve as irony later on in the musical?

Comment: On a side note, I'm also aware that Alexander Hamilton actually met Burr much later on in his life (contrary to what's suggested in the play).